# Distribution of $R = \sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ if $(X_1,X_2)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit disk

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X=(X_1,X_2)$ be continuously uniformly distributed on the unit disk $K$, i.e. the density of $X$ on $(\mathbb{R}^2,B_2, \lambda_2)$ is $f_X = \frac{1}{\pi} \mathbb{1}_K$. Determine the distribution function, the density and the expectation $E[R]$ for $R = \sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$.

My idea was to compute first the density using the transformation  rule for densities. So the joint density is $f_X = \frac{1}{\pi} \mathbb{1}_K$. My image is $R = \Phi(X)=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$. So $\Phi: \begin{bmatrix}
   x\\
   y
\end{bmatrix} = \Phi(x_1,x_2)= \begin{bmatrix}
   \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\\
   x_2
\end{bmatrix}.$ Therefore $\begin{bmatrix}
   x_1\\
   x_2
\end{bmatrix} = \Phi^{-1}(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
   \sqrt{x^2-x_1^2}\\
   y
\end{bmatrix}.$ So the Jacobi matrix equals

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-x_1^2}} &\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x^2-x_1^2}}\\
   0 &1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

So the determinant equals $det = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-x_1^2}}$

The transformation formula is $f_Y(y) = f_X(\Phi^{-1}(y)) \mid det J_{\Phi^{-1}}(y) \mid$ but I don't know now, how to proceed..

Comment: First mistake: the image should not be what you write but $\Phi(X)=(R,Y)$ with $R=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ and $Y=X_2$. Then $\Phi^{-1}$ is not what you write but $$\Phi^{-1}(r,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
  \pm \sqrt{r^2-y^2}\\
   y
\end{bmatrix}$$ Next mistake: the sign of the two top entries of the Jacobian matrix cannot be the same. Next mistake: The transformation formula is certainly not "$f_Y(y)$ equals anything" but $$f_{R,Y}(r,y) = f_X(\Phi^{-1}(r,y)) \,|\det J_{\Phi^{-1}}(r,y)|$$ Can you correct all these and complete your solution?

Comment: So the Jacobian equals $\begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}} &-\frac{y}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}\\
  0 &1
\end{bmatrix}$ and the corresponding determinant equals $\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}$. Then $f_{R,Y}(r,y) = f_x(\Phi^{-1}(r,y)) \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}} = \mathbb{1}_{K'} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}$ where $K' = \{ r \mid r^2 \leq 1\}$. So to get to the density of $R$, I have to integrate, i.e. $f(r) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}} \mathbb{1}_{K'} dy = \frac{r}{\pi} \arctan(\frac{y}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}) \mathbb{1}_{K'}$, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Yes, $f_R(r)=\int f_{R,Y}(r,y)dy$ but watch out for the limits of the $dy$ integral and that the result cannot depend on $y$.

Comment: Hmm what are the limits for $y$?  I know that $r^2=x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, so $y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$, but does that help?

Comment: No -- for each $r$, you want the limits of $y$ in terms of $r$. (Note that your $r^2=x^2+y^2$ introduces a pretty awful mess in the notations...)

Comment: Yeah, I've probably meant $r^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2$...so I guess the limits of $y$ in terms of $r$ is $0$ to $r$?

Comment: @Did Could you give me a hint or help me for the limits of $y$ in terms of $r$?

Comment: ?? Obviously, $-r\leqslant y\leqslant r$.

Comment: Right, and therefore I should get $f(r) = r$, $E[R] = \int_0^1 rf(r)dr = \frac{1}{3}$ and $F(R) = \int_0^r f(x) dx = \frac{r^2}{2}$ right?

Comment: Or souldn't the limits of the integral for the expectation be from $-1$ to $1$, since $r$ could be any value in between?

Comment: See previous comment. At this point, my advice would be to stop posting bizarre comments and to start writing down a full answer to your own question, so that people can see if you got the picture right and, if you did not, correct you.